# ArcGIS 10.2 Copy Rows error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I'm very confused by this one. I have run a polygon neighbors analysis in ArcGIS 10.2 and appended some data from another table to help me whittle down the neighbors list before my next action. So I have the following:

```
bn = "BLPUs_PolygonNeighbors"
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(bn, "Neighborscut")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Neighborscut", "NEW_SELECTION", where2)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Neighborscut", "SUBSET_SELECTION", where1)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Neighborscut", "SUBSET_SELECTION", where3)
arcpy.Delete_management(bn)
arcpy.CopyRows_management("Neighborscut", "BLPUs_PolygonNeighbors")
```

But when I run this, it says ERROR 000733: Output Table: Same as input C:\Users\Ant\Documents\ArcGIS\ITN.gdb\BLPUs_PolygonNeighbors
Failed to execute (CopyRows).

Which seems to suggest it thinks "Neighborscut" is actually also called "BLPUs_PolygonNeighbors"

Any ideas??

Comment: Try commenting out your three SelectByAttributes statements and I will bet you still get the same error. That will let you focus more on what the remaining lines of code are doing.

Comment: but even if they aren't applying a selection, I'm deleting "BLPUs_PolygonNeighbors" before the copy so how can it claim it already exists? Surely the error message is to do with the names being the same rather than the content of the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your source is:

> bn = "BLPUs_PolygonNeighbors"

And your destination is:

> arcpy.CopyRows_management("Neighborscut", "BLPUs_PolygonNeighbors")

They are the same, so the error is normal. It can not read from a table and at the same time writing to the same path. Note that a tableview is not the data. To do what you want, you have to have intermediate data.

So If you still want to overwrite your original table, you can do:

```
bn_disk = "BLPUs_PolygonNeighbors"
bn="in_memory\\BLPUs_PolygonNeighbors"
arcpy.CopyRows_management(bn_disk,bn)
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(bn, "Neighborscut")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Neighborscut", "NEW_SELECTION", where2)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Neighborscut","SUBSET_SELECTION", where1)
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("Neighborscut","SUBSET_SELECTION", where3)
arcpy.Delete_management(bn_disk)
arcpy.CopyRows_management("Neighborscut", bn_disk)
```

Comment: cheers, that sorted it :-)